# How to find out the following matrix P given below?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the matrix $A=~$
 $\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & -3 \\
-2 & 6 & 9 \\
3 & -9 & 4 \end{array} \right]$.

What matrix $P$ with non negative integer entries would have determinant $2$ and would satisfy

$P^tAP=~$ $\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -38 \end{array} \right]$

where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers with $a\lt b$

Now First of all i find value of $a$ and $b$ which comes out to be $1$ and $2$ by evaluating determinant on both sides.

But futher how to find out the matrix $P$?

Comment: It seems close to the concept of diagonalising the matrix via a similarity transform, thus the diagonal matrix should contain the eigenvalues of $A.$ However, $-38$ is not an eigenvalue of $A.$ I suppose it is still possible to find a $P$ but we know that $P$ must not be orthogonal otherwise there would be a similarity transform.

Comment: but $P$ is not orthogonal here as its determinant is $2$.